# Changing length of lines in a legend

Tags: r, legend

The following simple example...

```
plot(c(1,2),c(1,2),type="l")
legend(1,1.5,legend="Test",lty=1,seg.len=2)
```

...produces the error

> `Error in legend(1, 1.5, legend = "Test", lty = 1, seg.len = 2) : 
>     unused argument (seg.len = 2)`

How should I use `seg.len` to get longer lines in legends?

Comment: No, it doesn't... it works fine for me. Do you have all packages and R up to date?

Comment: This is extremely strange. When I restart my R session and run the little example I sent you, everything works fine. When I run my larger program, I get the same error again. However, when I then save my workspace, restart my R session, load the workspace and just run the code to generate the plot again, everything works as it should. It seems it is not my code that is the problem, but R seems to enter a strange state where it produces the error. When I restart the session and load the workspace again, everything works as it should.

Comment: seems like your `legend()` is masked by other packages. See my answer. This should solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this in a larger script, other packages might mask the `legend()` function. These "other" functions might not contain the `seg.len` parameter.  Thus you have to reference to the basic `legend` function. You can easily achieve this by adding the package like this:

```
graphics::legend(1, 1.5, legend = "Test", lty = 1, seg.len = 2)
```

Comment: Excellent - that was it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code in question works perfectly for me (see image output below).

I suggest you do the following:

1. Download and install the latest R binaries. [Download R](https://cran.r-project.org/)
2. If you use RStudio, download and install the most recent version. [Download RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/)

[image]

Comment: This is extremely strange. I have reinstalled. When I run the little example I sent you, everything works fine. When I run my larger program, I get the same error again. However, when I then save my workspace, restart my R session, load the workspace and just run the code to generate the plot again, everything works as it should.

It seems it is not my code that is the problem, but R seems to enter a strange state where it produces the error. When I restart the session and load the workspace again, everything works as it should.

Comment: I see. At least updating R solved one problem. I suggest you post another question with the new problem encountered, so the community can look into it and assist. And by the way, if my answer solved this particular question and you received some help from it, why the downvote on my answer??

Comment: I think updating R did not change anything. Simply restarting the R session produced the change. However, it was not me who downvoted you. I have now upvoted you to compensate, though!